# Is it possible to start administering a linux box via Ansible with just the root account and its password?

Tags: configuration, ansible

I recently rented a Linux box and I intend to provision it using [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible). I'd like to use [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) as early as possible in the process. At this stage I only have a root account and the corresponding password.

#### Questions

- Given the fact that my target box as well as OpenSSH-Server is running, would it be possible to copy my public key to the server and configure it with Ansible at this early stage?
- Do I have to manually copy the pub key to the server and configure ssh for Ansible to be able to communicate with the server in the first place?

EDIT 1:

I should've mentioned, that after reading the docs I used the following syntax:

```
ansible <nameoftargetbox> -m ping -u root -k
```

The command basically means use user root ( -u ) and ask for password ( -k ). I am correctly prompted for the password, but I keep getting this response:

```
 <nameoftargetbox>| FAILED => to use -c ssh with passwords, you must install the sshpass program
```

Needless to say that a common `ssh root@<targetbox>` works flawlessly.

After researching some more I found a solution in the Ansible github issue tracker. I'll post it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending `-c paramiko` to `ansible <nameoftargetbox> -m ping -u root -k` forces Ansible to use the *Paramiko Python library* internally which appearently does not have to have sshpass installed. Please consult [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3564) closed issue on the Ansible github issue tracker.

EDIT1:

To answer the original question, yes it is possible to administer a Linux box using Ansible with the root account and the password. One could use the `-c paramiko` switch in the first place to copy the pubkey to the target and doing some more bootstrapping before switching to using full blown Ansible Playbooks.

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to use Ansible with a fresh Ubuntu machine. I'll assume you are on an Ubuntu box, your user on the remote machine is `ubuntu`, and your remote machine is `REMOTE.COM` (you can use an IP address as well). Take these steps:

1. Copy your public ssh key to the remote machine so that you don't need to type your password to login.

   ```
   ssh-copy-id ubuntu@REMOTE.COM
   ```

   If you don't have an SSH key, use `ssh-keygen` and follow the prompts.
2. SSH into the remote server (you should not need to type your password);

   ```
   ssh ubuntu@REMOTE.COM
   ```
3. Setup your ubuntu user to be able to sudo without password (you'll need your password for this):

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo "ubuntu ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/ubuntu'
   ```
4. Ensure that python and python-apt are installed on the box:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python python-apt
   ```
5. Back to your local machine

   ```
   exit
   ```
6. Setup your ANSIBLE_HOSTS file (say remote.hosts) with:

   ```
   [www]
   REMOTE.COM ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
   ```

You're done. Now you can run your playbook with:

```
ANSIBLE_HOSTS=`pwd`/remote.hosts ansible-playbook -v site.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on these bullets from the official documents I would say you should be able to do what you want using just ssh without issue.

> - Dead simple setup
> - Super fast & parallel by default
> - No server or client daemons; use existing SSHd
> - No additional software required on client boxes
> - Modules can be written in ANY language
> - Awesome API for creating very powerful distributed scripts
> - Be usable as non-root
> - The easiest config management system to use, ever.

- Source: https://github.com/ansible/ansible

This is also echoed in the user's manual and documentation.

> By default, Ansible 1.3 and later will try to use native OpenSSH for
>   remote communication when possible. This enables both ControlPersist
>   (a performance feature), Kerberos, and options in ~/.ssh/config such
>   as Jump Host setup. When using Enterprise Linux 6 operating systems as
>   the control machine (Red Hat Enterprise Linux and derivatives such as
>   CentOS), however, the version of OpenSSH may be too old to support
>   Control Persist. On these operating systems, Ansible will fallback
>   into using a high-quality python implementation of OpenSSH called
>   ‘paramiko’. If you wish to use features like Kerberized SSH and more,
>   consider using Fedora, OS X, or Ubuntu as your control machine until a
>   newer version of OpenSSH is available for your platform – or engage
>   ‘accelerated mode’ in Ansible.

- Source: http://docs.ansible.com/intro_getting_started.html